# How can i add comment? nanopi neo

Tags: comments

## How can i add  comment for an interesting post?

I have not enough reputation to add a comment, but how can i get enough reputation?
I have tried to search the stackoverflow, but i find nothing.
i can not add a comment on a post.

i did not get a clue on how to add my reputation.

Where can i find something helpful for my question.

I really need help!
This site is not kind to non-english speaker!

nano-pi neo  how to compile kernel for it?

```
-  
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    place-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 9px #aaa;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```